# Is http://tsa.starfieldtech.com still working?

Tags: certificate, code-signing, signing, code-signing-certificate

Trying to sign an OutlookAdd-In with a GoDaddy certificate using http://tsa.starfieldtech.com as the Timestamp server, but was getting "signing parameter is incorrect".  Now getting "An error occurred while signing: Timestamp URL server name or address could not be resolved."  I successfully utilized http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode in order to get it out to users but am not completely comfortable using a new URL.  Are others experiencing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my 2¢:

As of a couple of days ago, GoDaddy withdrew from the code signing certificate (CSC) business. GoDaddy have told me they will honor my certificate till its expiry, which is 2023.

GoDaddy tech support tell me that `starfieldtech.com`, GoDaddy's recommended TSA (Time Stamp Authority) server, no longer recognizes GoDaddy CSCs. Using MS SDK `signtool.exe`, I have tried the following alternatives, all of which fail with the error "*The specified timestamp server either could not be reached or returned an invalid response*.":

```
http://tsa.starfieldtech.com/
http://timestamp.digicert.com?alg=sha1
http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
http://www.startssl.com/timestamp
http://rfc3161timestamp.globalsign.com/advanced
https://timestamp.geotrust.com/tsa
http://tsa.startssl.com/rfc3161
http://www.trustcenter.de/codesigning/timestamp
http://freetsa.org/tsr/
http://freetsa.org
https://freetsa.org
```

The only one that still works is:

```
http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode
```

I'm skeptical that TSA server is sufficient, I think the problem goes deeper than that.

I have also reviewed https://gist.github.com/Manouchehri/fd754e402d98430243455713efada710.

Does anyone know of other reputable TSAs that work?

I'd rather not have to prematurely replace my expensive CSC.

Comment: Do this address 'http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode' 
also just stopped working today?

Comment: I have seen "timestamp.comodoca.com" randomly fail recently, but I have kept trying repeatedly, and it works eventually.

Answer (score 1):

It's dead.

Browser shows `Server not found`.

Name resolution fails:

```
nslookup tsa.starfieldtech.com

...
can't find tsa.starfieldtech.com.: Non-existent domain
```

Comment: This is shocking considering GoDaddy tells you to use it and has no follow up on their site (https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-your-time-stamping-server-url-5412). Thanks for your research.